# How to replace the column value in select statement in Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query like i want to replace the column value with Available if its not empty otherwise Not Available.

```
select CandidateID,ResumeName from dbo.Tbl_Candidates 
where CreatedBy=UserId order by CandidateID DESC
```

In this case if ResumeName is not empty i want to replace with Available else Not Available.This help me out to get this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select CandidateID, case when ResumeName = '' Then 'Not Available' Else 'Available' End as Availability 
from dbo.Tbl_Candidates 
where CreatedBy=UserId 
order by CandidateID DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select CandidateID,
case 
   when ResumeName is null then 'Not Available'
   when ResumeName = '' then 'Not Available'
   else 'Available'
end as ResumeName from dbo.Tbl_Candidates 
where CreatedBy=UserId order by CandidateID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CandidateID,CASE WHEN ISNULL(ResumeName,'') = '' 'Not Available' ELSE 'Available' END AS ResumeAvailability from dbo.Tbl_Candidates 
where CreatedBy=UserId order by CandidateID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CandidateID,ISNULL(ResumeName,'Not Available') as ResumeName    
 from dbo.table 
where CreatedBy=UserId order by CandidateID DESC
```